# Minor Drupal upgrade for the first time. 1 Error and 2 warnings

Tags: updating

I am trying to upgrad 7.18 to 7.19. I followed the upgrade.txt procedure. After going to Administration > Reports > Status report I see 1 error and 2 warnings. How significant are they? Do I need to do something about them?

Error
Database schema Inconsistent
The Schema comparison report shows:

```
28 modules with matching tables
5 extra tables
2 modules with mis-matching tables
```

I've had a look at the database schema comparison report but how am I meant to make sense out of it?

Warnings

Drupal core update status   No available releases found
There was a problem checking available updates for Drupal. See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.

Module and theme update status  Out of date
There are updates available for one or more of your modules or themes. To ensure the proper functioning of your site, you should update as soon as possible. See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.

Comment: You have three questions about problems with your site upgrade.  Something is *seriously* wrong with your site.  I suspect you deleted some modules w/o disabling and uninstalling them first.  Please spend some time diagnosing what is wrong, and come back with some concrete information and try to solve one thing at a time instead of spreading the problem across multiple quesions.

Comment: thank you @MPD
Any tops on how to diagnose what is wrong? :(

Comment: *tips, not tops